# Connection string using Windows Authentication run on other user

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have DB with tech user in Active Directory. Application is run on IIS on default user and can't be changed. In normal case I create a tech user on SQL and use simple connection string like this:

```
Data Source=xxx; Initial Catalog=DbName; User ID=User; Password=Password
```

But because i need use a window authentication on user what was create on AD, I should use something like this:

```
Data Source=xxx Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=True
```

But if I use this case i need to run my application on same user what is use for login to DB.

My question is. It is possible to use Windows Authentication to login to DB using another account?
For example:
My application work on user ABC,
To login to DB i have user CBA

Comment: Your IIS app pool identity should be set to the AD user that has access to the db.  If that can't be changed you will have problems.

Comment: Yes i know but in my case change it isn't possible

Comment: Then you would need to set up impersonation, but that would be passing the authentication of the user through to the db which is not the same thing as you describe.  Can you not use SQL Logins?

Comment: Ok i reade about impersonation. Thanks for tips:)